# jquery selecting parent from this and then its child

Tags: jquery, this, parent-child, parent

I need to select a parent of 'this' element then it's child can you see if my code is correct?

```
$(this).click(function(){
  $(this).parent('li').child('p').toggle();
  $(this).not(this).parent('li').child('p').toggle('hide');
});
```

This is actually for a html which looks somewhat like this

```
<ul>
  <li><header>Header 1</header><p>Content 1</p></li>
  <li><header>Header 2</header><p>Content 2</p></li>
</ul>
```

Can you explain me whether if the script is correct?

Comment: What do you expect `$(this).not(this)` to select? And what is `$(this)`, in context? Given that it looks like you're trying to show/hide the `<p>` by clicking the `<header>`, I'd strongly suggest `$('header').click(function() { $(this).parent().find('p').toggle(); });`

Comment: It's actually i want to select the <p> in all <li> except this!

Comment: $(this).click --> is this part of a another function, can you post that?

Comment: If want to see if code is correct, just try it

Comment: Sorry its actually an accordion which i tried to do on my own

Comment: Then you need to explain the problem you're trying to solve, please: [edit] your question and add the details we don't know so that we can understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var $contents = $("ul p"); // get 'em all! (and use class to be more specific)

$('header').click(function(){
  var $myContent = $(this).closest('li').find('p'); // this content
  $contents.not($myContent).hide();                 // hide all other
  $myContent.toggle();                              // this content toggle
});
```

```css
ul p{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><header>Header 1</header><p>Content 1</p></li>
  <li><header>Header 2</header><p>Content 2</p></li>
  <li><header>Header 3</header><p>Content 3</p></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Got it roko! but mine too worked just changed the parameter in not(this)

Comment: @Makk well, your question was a bit fuzzy so thought to improve the code overall. ;) Hope I got the answer right.

Comment: ya it looks great!

Comment: means? did'nt get you?